# Revive Adserver XML_RPC Sending Image Content

Tags: php, image, xml-rpc

I am trying to send a photo via xml_rpc like this:

```
$data = array(
    'phpads55deb65dd5ca45.43027895',
    'aImage' => array(
        'filename' => $file['aImage']['name'],
        'content' => file_get_contents($file['aImage']['tmp_name']),
    ),
    'campaignId' => 1,
    'storageType' => 'web'
);

$this->client = new Client('http://example.com/api/v2/xmlrpc/');
$this->client->call('ox.addBanner',  $data);
```

I get the request via Fiddler witch shows this:

```
POST http://example.com/api/v2/xmlrpc/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 771
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: Zend_XmlRpc_Client
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>ox.addBanner</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>phpads55deb65dd5ca45.43027895</string>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member><name>campaignId</name><value><int>1</int></value></member> 
                    <member>
                        <name>bannerName</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>khgjjhj</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>aImage</name>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member>
                                    <name>filename</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <string>logo.png</string>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                                <member>
                                    <name>content</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <string>�PNG&#13;</string>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>comments</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>dfgdgdfgdfg</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>storageType</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>web</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params></methodCall>
```

And as you can see the full image is not there in the request. What is the problem? I tested `fread` instead of `file_get_content` but there is no difference. The XML Parser sends this error:

> XML error: Invalid character at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value format was not correct. I had to change this line

```
'content' => file_get_contents($file['aImage']['tmp_name']),
```

to

```
'content' => new Base64(file_get_contents($file['aImage']['tmp_name'])),
```

which needs this to be imported

```
use Zend\XmlRpc\Value\Base64;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed binary content like that in an XML response. You should consider base 64 encoding the binary image into a base 64 string. You can do like this:

```
$filename = $file['aImage']['tmp_name'];
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$base64 = base64_encode($fileData);

$data = array(
    'phpads55deb65dd5ca45.43027895',
    'aImage' => array(
        'filename' => $filename,
        'content' => $base64
    ),
    'campaignId' => 1,
    'storageType' => 'web'
);
```

Comment: I tested this too. Did not work! The problem is that the remote server does not use base64. And about embedding binary content you are compeletly correct.

Comment: @Abadis You mean you cannot encode the string? Or why did it not work?

Comment: The remote server is Revive Adserver. I want to find if there are other encodings that I have not tested or if sth is wronge in my codes. You can find it here : http://www.revive-adserver.com/

Comment: There is base64 functionality [in the library](https://github.com/revive-adserver/revive-adserver/blob/master/lib/max/Delivery/base64.php). So it seems it should support base 64 encoding?

Comment: @Abadis While encoding? Maybe your file is not a proper image?

Comment: Added a bug to github in here : https://github.com/revive-adserver/revive-adserver/issues/613   and got my answer. thanks every one.

Comment: @Abadis They said it is not a bug but that you need to add the data in base64 format. Is that answer not exactly the same?

Comment: I just added the correct answer here for others! And yes your answers were correct too! thanks!